Den/Dem Rechten zu sehen
I was watching "Die Chaos Kompanie" and what is the difference between "Ins ganze Land wurden Inspekteure geschickt, um nach den/dem Rechten zu sehen"?

"Nach dem Rechten sehen" is a fixed phrase that means something along the lines of "to go look if everything is ok", "to check on something", "to see whether there's any problem that might need to be taken care of". So

Ins ganze Land wurden Inspekteure geschickt, um nach dem Rechten zu sehen.

could be translated as

Inspectors were sent out all across the land, to check that everything was on the up and up.

EDIT: You may want to notice that the phrase is in singular, "nach dem Rechten sehen". "Das Rechte" in this case means something like "the right thing", "the proper thing", "how it is supposed to be". So, a literal translation of "nach dem Rechten sehen" could be something like "to check on the right thing" or "to look after the right thing".
The plural form, "nach den Rechten sehen", is of course grammatical, but not an established phrase. You could use it, for example, when checking the permission settings in a software system:

Ich muss noch nach den Rechten sehen.
I still have to look into the permissions.

But the plural version doesn't have a fixed meaning as a phrase.

What about "nach den Rechten sehen"

@MaximBaurov The plural form isn't an established phrase. I added further information to my answer.

Or “den Rechten” could be dative of “die Rechten”, possibly referring to right-wingers.

The phrase is a pun between the expression "nach dem Rechten sehen" which means "to check if everything is ok" and "nach den Rechten sehen" in the sense of "see what those from the right wing are up to".
